# Android FrameLayout ListView elements don't appear clickable

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an application that loads items into a ListView that is inside a FrameLayout. That part works fine but the `click` functionality doesn't seem to work, when I hover over the items they don't have the clickable hover appearance and when clicked do nothing.

I've Googled around and there's some mentions of focus and clickable types in the xml but having tried adding these they don't seem to make any difference.

Is there something wrong with the layout structure that I'm using? or can I add something to ensure the ListView elements are clickable?

**LansFragment**

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
JSONArray lanArray = data; //json arrray, blank for example

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    ArrayList<String> itemArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        JSONArray jsonMainArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray(lanArray);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject json_data = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = json_data.getString("lanName");
            String key = json_data.getString("lanKey");

            itemArray.add(name);
            myMap.put(name, key);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // catch here
    }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), R.layout.activity_listview, itemArray);

    ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {

            String lan = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String key = myMap.get(lan);

            // Not currently working due to no click registering
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.stats.LansFragment"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listview" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_listview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: Why even have that FrameLayout at all?

Comment: @CodyCaughlan I'm using fragments but it would've been too much code to demo here so I've left parts out

Comment: Your call the listview id inside your fragment calls `ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);` it should be `ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);`

Comment: @MarkKeen that's the one, if you answer it I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call the to the `ListView` id inside your fragment calls:

`ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);`

But inside your fragment you should reference the Fragment view. It should be:

`ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);`